# How to set leading in TextBox?

Tags: wpf, textbox

I have a TextBox control with some text. I want to modify this: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leading) in that TextBox.

How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use TextBlock.LineHeight and TextBlock.LineStackingStrategy :-)

Comment: It gets the job done, but: Now i can't select my text. So... how to change that?

Comment: I cant reproduce your problem. <TextBox TextBlock.LineHeight="200"/> works fine and as expected for me.